# Is it possible to access the BTable props outside of the table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I would like to close the details of one row from within an another row. My plan is to use the index number of each row to check the `showdetails` value. Unfortunately I have not been able to access one row object from within another. 
Using the the vue developer Chrome extension I was able to see that the `BTable` component has the information I need but how can I access the `BTable` object?

Screenshot of vue developer tools with `BTable`:

[image: screenshot]

Example fiddle for BootstrapVue Table: https://jsfiddle.net/seeing/3s97kmjb/2/

Comment: Please provide code or any working fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advice against mutating internal props of components.

Why aren't you using the items collection you pass to the table in the first place.
Could also help if you explained a bit more in depth what the end goal is.

You could do something like, which doesn't require accessing the bTable.
https://jsfiddle.net/vyk28r3o/1/

Remember to use `this.$set` if the property doesn't exist on the item to keep Vue's Reactivity happy.

Comment: Hiws is correct.  Mutate the original items array that you are pssing to `b-table`, by setting the `_showDetails` row property: `this.$set(this.items, rowIndex, true/false)`